# What is missing in my configuration for PAM user mapping to work?

Tags: mariadb

Using Community edition of MariaDB 10.11.2. Following the instructions on this page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-and-group-mapping-with-pam/

I'm able to successfully authenticate with these types of users

1. A user created in MariaDB with a strong password
2. A user created in MariaDB identified via pam using the 'mariadb' service. This user's account is a Linux OS account.
3. A user created in MariaDB identified via pam using the 'mariadb' service. This user's account is only in LDAP on another server.

So I know that my PAM and LDAP configuration is working correctly. But I'm not able to do the user mapping that would let me authenticate with any users who do not have a MariaDB account identified via pam. I've followed the instructions on the webpage in the Creating User section

1. Created user 'bar'@'%' that has a password
2. Cleaned up any defaults by deleting entries from mysql.db for the ''@'%' user
3. Created a new user ''@'%' that is identified via pam, and set that as the proxy for the users that I want to map

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX9sq.png)

In my case, I'm not doing the dba group so I left that out, and the proxy grant is to my 2 users, colegate and xetron.

Then I edited the /etc/security/user_map.conf file to have these 2 entries:

```
colegate: bar
xetron: bar
```

The pam_user_map.so is loaded in /lib64/security. The /etc/pam.d/mariadb service file works for accounts that are identified via pam:

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so audit
auth sufficient pam_lap.so audit
auth required pam_user_map.so debug
account required pam_unix.so audit
account required pam_ldap.so audit
```

I don't get any message in journalctl so I'm stumped for why the mapping isn't occurring and what I could be missing. Any suggestions from anyone?

Tried following instructions from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-and-group-mapping-with-pam/ and expected the mapping to work - it doesn't.